# Import trace for requested module: ./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js ./pages/index.js

Tags: next.js, sanity, thirdweb

```
Can someone please help me out with the error? I'm stuck on this for hours
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7BbX.png)



And im unable to proceed further as it says: This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed      by fixing the error.The following code started to throw errors like this:
```

const sdk = new ThirdwebSDK(
new ethers.Wallet(

```
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_METAMASK_KEY,
  ethers.getDefaultProvider(
    'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/'
    ),
),
```

)

```
const Portfolio = () => {
    const [sanityTokens, setSanityTokens] = useState([])
    const [thirdWebTokens, setThirdWebTokens] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getSanityAndThirdWebTokens = async () => {
        
            const coins = await fetch(
                " some url"
            )
            const SanityTokens = (await coins.json()).result
            setSanityTokens(SanityTokens)
            setThirdWebTokens(
                sanityTokens.map(token => (sdk.getTokenModule(token.contractAddress))
                )
            )
    }
    return getSanityAndThirdWebTokens();
}, [])

console.log('sanity ⚰️', sanityTokens)
console.log('sanity ', thirdWebTokens)
```

I've searched everywhere for a solution, but cant find one. And what is up with the Can't resolve './error' thing??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.